# how to throwError in switchMap in the ngrx effect

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I am using ngrx8, rxjs6 and angular 9

After login I need to call another service. when that service is throwing error I want to catchError part of my effect to handle it, the issue is I catch the error in try catch and I see the log, but `catchError` is not triggered.

### Simplified code

```
    login$ = createEffect(() => {
        return this.actions$.pipe(

            ofType(AuthActions.login),
            switchMap((action) =>
                this.userService.login(action.userName, action.password)
                    .pipe(
                        switchMap((token) => {
                            return throwError(new Error('hello'));
                        }),
                        map((token) => AuthActions.loginSuccess()),
                        catchError((error) => {
                            console.error('error', error); // I don't see this in console

                            return of(AppError({ error }));
                        })),
            ),
            catchError((error) => {
                console.error('error 2', error);

                return of(AppError({ error }));
            }),
        );
    });
```

### My real code

```
    login$ = createEffect(() => {
        return this.actions$.pipe(

            ofType(AuthActions.login),
            switchMap((action) =>
                this.userService.login(action.userName, action.password)
                    .pipe(
                        switchMap(async (token) => {
                            try {
                                await this.matrixService.initClient(action.userName, action.password);

                                return of(token);
                            }
                            catch (error) {
                                console.log('catch error', error); // I see this in console

                                return throwError(error);
                            }
                        }),
                        map((token) => AuthActions.loginSuccess()),
                        catchError((error) => {
                            console.error('error', error); // I don't see this in console

                            return of(AppError({ error }));
                        })),
            ),
            catchError((error) => {
                console.error('error 2', error);

                return of(AppError({ error }));
            }),
        );
    });
```

console output
[image]

Comment: `switchMap` doesn't wait for `async` function

Comment: @RafiHenig how to solve it?

Comment: `@Reza` fixed my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using `Async-Await` syntax to wait for the `Promise` returned by `matrixService.initClient` to complete (which wouldn't work in the current context due to `switchMap` operator not waiting for `async` functions), consider returning it without waiting for it, as it would be converted into an `Observable` (thanks to `switchMap` operator accepting `Promise`) resulting in `this.userService.login` being awaited.

```js
login$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$
  .pipe(
    ofType(AuthActions.login),
    switchMap(({ userName, password }) => this.userService.login(userName, password)
      .pipe(
        switchMap(() => this.matrixService.initClient(userName, password)),
        map((token) => AuthActions.loginSuccess()),
        catchError((error) => {
          console.error('error', error);
          return of(AppError({ error }));
        })
      )
    ),
    catchError((error) => {
      console.error('error 2', error);
      return of(AppError({ error }));
    })
  )
);
```

Comment: Yes, this works, although I needed to dispatch loginSuccess even after initClient throws an error

Answer (score 0):

based on the comments i will modify the previous answers a little bit

```
login$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$
  .pipe(
    ofType(AuthActions.login),
    switchMap(({ userName, password }) => this.userService.login(userName, password)
      .pipe(
        map((token) => AuthActions.loginSuccess())
        tap(() => this.matrixService.initClient(userName, password)),
      )
    ),
    catchError((error) => {
      console.error('error 2', error);
      return of(AppError({ error }));
    })
  )
);
```

I switch the order, always firing `AuthActions.loginSuccess()` and then `this.matrixService.initClient(userName, password)`.

`catchError` does not need to be called twice, any error generated from service call will be catch in the outermost `catchError` operator.